# Bootstrap 3 styling attempts not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the relevant [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j9q1ye4/) with full code sample.

I am trying to:

- Change the color of the footer's `<hr/>`, however my styling rule doesn't seem to work; and
- Figure out why, if you break the page out into a fullscreen, the page appears too wide and the browser presents you with a horizontal scrollbar

My CSS rule to color the `<hr/>` is:

```
hr {
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

And as for why the page is too wide, I'm totally out of ideas. Any idea as to why my attempts here aren't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hr` tag use the property `border` to set the line ... if you need to change that color then use:

> border-top-color

Try this:

```
footer hr {
  border-top-color:blue;
}
```

The **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j9q1ye4/1/)**

And the scroll bar on the page is because you are breaking the layout with the `absolute position` on the footer. http://jsfiddle.net/7j9q1ye4/2/

Answer (score 0):

The HR will go over the whole Div so it depends how big the div is,
if the width of the div where the HR is within is over the whole page wide that the HR will do the same. It has probably something to do with the DIV where the HR is standing in.